# Filter request per category WordPress Rest Api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Is it possible to filter the results of a GET request made using the WordPress REST API by category? In this particular case I want to retrieve the posts of a particular author written in a specific category because the author written many articles and I'm interest in one category of posts. I've tried to use `categories` in the http url but it doesn't work in combination with `author` and `posts` keywords.

This is my url at the moment: `http://mysite.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=1`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want post by author id 1 or 2 in categories 5 or 4 just do:

```
http://mysite.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author[]=1&author[]=2&categories=5,4
```